# Game Manager that controls two characters

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

I have a question.

I'm trying to make a runner game with 2 characters not one. I've done the movement and the camera related stuff.

Now I'm trying to add the Game Manager.

The problem is that my Game Manager isn't able to accesss the `PlayerMotor` of both characters.

I found a tutorial on Youtube that uses a singleton but it accesses only one player character which is obvious cause it's a singleton. So can you help me out guys? Unfortunately I'm not a programmer so I can't figure it out.

How can the Game Manager access both of their `PlayerMotor` instances to start the game?

Comment: Can you share some code with us? Would be nice to have some context on the issue.

Comment: Are those players already in the scene when the scene loads? Or you are using some script to instantiate them into the scene.

Answer (score 1):

From: **[Unity - Scripting API: Object.FindObjectsOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html)**

You can retrieve your `Playermotor` scripts by using `FindObjectsOfType` like that:

```cs
var playersMotor = Object.FindObjectsOfType<Playermotor>(); // find Playermotor scripts in your scene and store it in playersMotor
```

Or:

```cs
var playersMotor = Object.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Playermotor));
```